# Kotlin generic type, Type inference failed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Kotlin reference document said this example is valid.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds

```
fun <T> cloneWhenGreater(list: List<T>, threshold: T): List<T>
    where T : Comparable<T>,
          T : Cloneable {
  return list.filter { it > threshold }.map { it.clone() }
}
```

But in Android studio 3.0, it shows thin red line under `it.clone()`. And error message is:

> Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch. 
>  Required: `List<T>`
>   
>  Found: `List<Any>`

Why this example cannot be compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `clone()`, which is `protected` as the compiler complains. The problem's already been discussed here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/is-the-documentation-correct/2925